# How to work with a clipping path in a tiff file using python?

Tags: python, image, vector, tiff, libtiff

"A TIFF file can include a vector-based clipping path (outlines, croppings, image frames)". Source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF#Features_and_options)

Here is an example of a such tiff image with a clipping path: [example.tif](http://stanpol.no/files/example.tif)

- How to get a clipping path from the file using python?
- How to write a clipping path to a new tiff file using python?

Comment: Yes, TIFFs can include vector based clipping paths. However, the path resource is an Adobe extension, read/written by Photoshop, inside a Photoshop-specific tag `34377`. This tag contains various Photoshop resources, among them you may find the clipping path. It is officially documented, in [*Photoshop-specific TIFF Tags*](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/photoshop/fileformatashtml/#50577413_61897), should you need to implement it yourself. :-)